# How do I return a Result data type in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-result

I have the code below

```
fn main() {
    let num: i64 = 600851475143;

    println!("Largest prime: {}", largest_prime_factor(num));


}

fn largest_prime_factor(num:i64) -> Result<i64, Error<None>> {
    let mut primes: Vec<i64> = Vec::new();

    for x in 1i64..=num {
     if num % x == 0 {
         if (x == 2) | (x==3) | ((x-1) % 6 ==0) | ((x+1) %6 ==0) {
             primes.push(x);
         }
     }
    }
    let max_value = primes.iter().max()?;

}
```

The `largest_prime_factor` function's role is to find the largest prime factor of the number in it's input.

I push all prime factors to the `primes` vector, and then return the largest, but I'm unsure how to return the largest integer. If the .max() function returns an error - the documents say it would return None, but when I place None as a possibility to return, it says it isn't a data type, and to use my variant's enum, but look at the docs, the None does seem to be the enum. So what does the function actually return? Am I using `?` incorrectly

Comment: > when I place None as a possibility to return, it says it isn't a data type
That's because in Rust, None is a variant of the `Option` enum.

Comment: There are a few other strange things there ... you only consider primes 2, 3, 5, and 7, but you still try all divisors up to num. Also, `||` is logical or, not `|`.

Comment: @nnnmmm thanks for the advice, they were just place holders while i could actually get my function to return something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [signature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max) for the `max` method, you can see that it returns an Option:

```
fn max(self) -> Option<Self::Item>
```

In this case, it returns `Option<i64>`.

The Option type is an enum which has two variants, to simplify:

```
enum Option<T> {
    Some(T),
    None,
}
```

Here, `None` isn't a type, but an enum variant.

Here is what your method should look like:

```
fn largest_prime_factor(num:i64) -> Option<i64> {
    let mut primes: Vec<i64> = Vec::new();

    for x in 1i64..=num {
     if num % x == 0 {
         if (x == 2) | (x==3) | ((x-1) % 6 ==0) | ((x+1) %6 ==0) {
             primes.push(x);
         }
     }
    }
    
    primes.iter().max().cloned()
}
```

You don't even need a Result type here, as it doesn't really make sense to return an error.

Returning an Option signals that there can be zero or one result.

Comment: Thanks. I got the error with the above code: 
mismatched types
expected enum `Option<i64>`
   found enum `Option<&i64>`
Did I do something wrong with my Vector?

Comment: Correct, iter will work on references, meaning Self::Item will be &i64 for max. It can be converted to an i64 for free using `cloned`, or by dereferencing.